# What is the best way to learn texmacs?

Tags: emacs, latex

I currently use Kile to edit LaTeX documents. I don't like kile for a couple of reasons so I was thinking of trying to learn how to use texmacs. I have been through a tutorial for emacs which I am now getting to grips with. The documentation for texmacs and auctex are pretty weak in terms of explaining how to install and how to use those things. A quick google search didn't show up any friendly "how-to"s on this topic. Are there any resources you can direct me to?

Comment: You are aware that TeXmac isn't LaTeX, right? Rather it is an emacs like editor with its own built-in latex-like markup language.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I meant Auctex, not texmacs...

Comment: Why close a question two years after the last activity on it? This question has answers, so I can't delete it. It's obviously naive and should be removed from the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit puzzled by your question.  I use Emacs+Auctex on Windows, Linux and OS X machines and have never had any problem installing them.  I'd suggest heading to http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/ and following the instructions.  If you have any more specific questions post again.

Answer (score 2):

sorry I can't help you with TeXmacs, I just wanted to note that this program isn't under active development for quite some time now. If you look at the [homepage](http://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/home/welcome.en.html) the copyright notice is until year 2003!

If you are looking for a more GUI oriented LaTeX editor I can recommend [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/). Emacs+AucTeX is of course wonderful, but it has a certain learning curve.

However if you plan to learn Emacs or are using it already, than you should definitely go for it!

Comment: For the record, TeXmacs is very much under active development, and has been for the past 16 years (probably longer)